# kindle not connecting to wi-fi

Tags: wi-fi, amazon-kindle

Whenever I am trying to connect my kindle to wi-fi it shows no internet found. Once my kindle got discharged to 0. So is that the reason why my kindle is not able to find any internet. If no, then why my kindle is not able to find any internet? And if yes, then what should I do so that it finds wi-fi again.

Comment: Please focus on one device only. In the title and the first part of your question you are talking about your Kindle. Later suddenly you are talking about your tablet/tab. In any way you please edit your question and include more details about your Wifi (settings) and your devices. Does the Wifi work without problems on other devices?

Comment: @Robert actually with tablet i meant kindle only but since u suggested i have edited tablet to kindle

Comment: So you are actually talking about an Amazon Fire HD tablet, not about a Kindle (these are the e-book reader with e-paper display)? Therefore to make it clear please include the full product name of the device you are talking about.

Comment: @Robert, I am talking about kindle not tablet and this is the final. It is kindle not a Amazon Fire HD tablet.

Comment: This site focuses on Android device, but a Kindle does not run on Android. Hence your question is unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: @Robert then can u please tell where can I ask kindle related issues?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know any Amazon related forum or Stackexchange site.